# What are the limits on value of goods during customs in Italy?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, italy, electronic-items

I am travelling to Italy to meet some friends and will be taking small-ish electronics like Kindles/e readers as a gift. Is there a limit on the value of goods? Where can I find information on the exemptions/rules regarding gifts and limits on the value of the goods I can carry?

The only reliable source seems to be the airport website, but all the links are in Italian and the browser translate function doesn't generate any easily understandable information. I did see a limit of 150 euros on the page but couldn't understand if that applied to gifts and what other stipulations might be in place.

Comment: Where are you coming to Italy from? Within the EU, or outside? (It makes a difference!)

Comment: I'll be travelling from the US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find some information in the web site of the [Italian customs](http://www.agenziadogane.it/wps/wcm/connect/Internet/ee/).

Being Italian, I find it quite embarrassing to realize that the f.a.q. section is not translated into English.

As far as I was able to understand reading the f.a.q. you can have with you imported goods for a maximum value of 430,00 €. The 150,00 € you were mentioning in the question is the limit for children under 15 years of age.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about entering the EU? It's the same all across the EU. The information you're looking for is [right here](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/common/travellers/enter_eu/index_en.htm).

> Other goods (including perfume, coffee, tea, electronic devices etc.):
>
> Up to a value of €430 for air and sea travellers
>
> The value on an individual item may not be split up.
>   The value of personal luggage (i.e. suitcases) and
>   medicinal products for the personal needs of the traveller do not
>   count. Member States may reduce the above limits to € 150 for
>   travellers under 15 years.